# Velocity Plugin For Rational (RSA 7.5.5)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor, velocity, rational-rsa

I Am new on Velocity, and added its plugins folders (org.apache.velocity_1.7.0, org.vaulttec.velocity.ui_1.0.3) after extracting them from there jars http://veloedit.sourceforge.net , and put them  in the plugins folder for my Eclipse (RSA) in that path ("C:\IBM\SDPShared\plugins"). but the .VM file opened using default editor not the plugin and can't find auto-complete there.

Note: i also can't see velocity view under Window -> show view -> other. so please advice how to get solution for this issue or another editor to use.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/ which still works ok with current Eclipse 3.7.2. It's easiest if you install it by going to "Help - Install new Software - Add" and enter the Update-Site http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/

Comment: Actually currently i'm using RSA (IBM Rational) 7.5.5, will check if your like will work on it.

Comment: i installed the plugin from the link u sent. but after installation when i checked the status i found "No plug-in: "com.googlecode.veloeclipse.ui" included at runtime.
".. that made the plugin not working. can u please advice?